# PHP on updating image changes to default

Tags: php, image-uploading, crud

We are working on our own MVC framework and on edit if we unchange the image, image changes to default. We don't want image to change in edit mode unless image is re selected.

Our code is as follows:

HTML (View)

```
<form id="form-category" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <a href="" id="thumb-image" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST ?>/image/<?php echo $data['industry_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['industry_name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $data['industry_name']; ?>"  data-placeholder="<?php echo HTTP_HOST ?>/image/<?php echo $data['placeholder']; ?>" width="100" height="100">
            <input type="hidden" name="delete_image" value="<?php echo $data['industry_image']; ?>">
        </a>
        <input type="file" class="hidden" name="industry_image" value="<?php echo $data['industry_image']; ?>" id="input-image" onchange="readURL(this);">
    </div>
</div>

</form>

jQuery for displaying image on file select
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#thumb-image').children('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```

jQuery for Bootstrap Popover

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=\'image\']', function(e) {
    var $element = $(this);
    var $popover = $element.data('bs.popover'); // element has bs popover?

    e.preventDefault();

    // destroy all image popovers
    $('a[data-toggle="image"]').popover('destroy');

    // remove flickering (do not re-add popover when clicking for removal)
    if ($popover) {
        return;
    }

    $element.popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        trigger: 'manual',
        content: function() {
            return '<button type="button" id="button-image" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button> <button type="button" id="button-clear" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>';
        }
    });

    $element.popover('show');

    $('#button-image').on('click', function() {
        $('#input-image').trigger('click');

        // $element.parent().find('input').attr('value', '');

        $element.popover('destroy');
    });

    $('#button-clear').on('click', function() {
        $element.find('img').attr('src', $element.find('img').attr('data-placeholder'));

        $element.parent().find('input').attr('value', '');
        //alert($('#input-image').attr('value', ''));

        $element.popover('destroy');
    });
});
```

Controller

```
$data = [
'industry_image' => isset($_POST['industry_image'] ? $_POST['industry_image'] : NULL
]

if(empty($_FILES['industry_image']['size'])) {
    $data['industry_image'] = 'no-image.png';
} else {
            $file = $_FILES['industry_image'];

            $fileName = $file['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $file['size'];
            $fileError = $file['error'];
            $fileType = $file['type'];

            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

            $allowed = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            $allowedFileSize = 2000000;

            if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
                if($fileError === 0) {
                    if($fileSize < $allowedFileSize) {
                        $fileNameNew = strtolower($data['industry_name']) . "." . $fileActualExt;
                        $fileDestination = DIR_IMAGE . 'industries/' . $fileNameNew;
                        $filePath = 'industries/' . $fileNameNew;

                        if(array_key_exists('delete_image', array($data['industry_image']))) {
                            if(file_exists($filePath)) {
                                unlink($filePath);
                            }
                        }

                        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

                        if($moveResult != true) {
                            echo "Error: File Upload Failed. Try again.";
                            unlink($fileTmpName);
                            exit;
                        } else {
                            if(file_exists($fileNameNew)) {
                                flash("file_alert alert-danger", "File already exists");
                            } else {
                                $data['industry_image'] = $filePath;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        flash("file_alert alert-danger", "File size is $fileSize of $allowedFileSize");
                    }
                } else {
                    flash("file_alert alert-danger", "Error uploading the file");
                }
            } else {
                $a = "Please upload only ";
                foreach($allowed as $ext) {
                    $a .= '<b>' . $ext . '</b>' . ', ';
                }
                $a .= " extensions";

                flash("file_alert alert-danger", $a);
            }
        }

if($this->model->getIndustries($industry_id, $data) {
    redirect("catalog/industries", $data);
} else {
    redirect("catalog/industries_form", $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function editIndustry($industry_id, $data) {
    # Prepare Query for category
    $this->db->query("UPDATE industry SET industry_name = :industry_name, industry_description = :industry_description, sort_order = :sort_order, status = :status WHERE industry_id = '" . $industry_id ."'");

    # Bind Values
    $this->db->bind(':industry_name', $data['industry_name']);
    $this->db->bind(':industry_description', $data['industry_description']);
    $this->db->bind(':sort_order', $data['sort_order']);
    $this->db->bind(':status', $data['status']);

    # Execute
    $this->db->execute();

    if(isset($data['industry_image'])) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE industry SET industry_image = :image WHERE industry_id = '" . $industry_id . "'");
        $this->db->bind(":image", $data['industry_image']);
        //$this->db->execute();
    }

    # Execute
    if($this->db->execute()) {
        return $industry_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Bootstrap popover image

[image: Edit Image]

Above code works but as mentioned earlier, image gets updated even if we don't select on POST. If the image is unedited, same image should go to database. If we clear the database with the red delete button, value gets clear from input tag should send **no-image.png** to the database.

Hope, I could explain my problem and looking for a solution from you'll awesome guys.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove - line - `$data['industry_image'] = 'no-image.png';` - that should fix that.

Comment: @Mr.Blue, thanks for your suggestion. $data['industry_image'] echoes EMPTY even though there is a value in the input tag.